# How to fix ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer CNN: expected shape=(None, 35), found shape=(None, 31)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am using Convolutional Neural Network to train a text classification task, using Keras, Conv1D. When I run the model below to my multi class text classification task, I get error such as following. I put time to undrestand the error but I don't know how to fix it. can anyone help me please?

The data set and evaluation set shape is such as following:

```
df_train shape: (7198,)
df_val shape: (1800,)
```

```
np.random.seed(42)
#You needs to reshape your input data according to Conv1D layer input format - (batch_size, steps, input_dim). Try


# set parameters of matrices and convolution
embedding_dim = 300
nb_filter = 64
filter_length = 5
hidden_dims = 32
stride_length = 1

from keras.layers import Embedding

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1,
                            embedding_dim,
                            input_length=35,
                            name="Embedding")
inp = Input(shape=(35,), dtype='int32')
embeddings = embedding_layer(inp)



conv1 = Conv1D(filters=32,  # Number of filters to use
                    kernel_size=filter_length, # n-gram range of each filter.
                    padding='same',  #valid: don't go off edge; same: use padding before applying filter
                    activation='relu',
                    name="CONV1",
                    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.0367))(embeddings)

conv2 = Conv1D(filters=32,  # Number of filters to use
                    kernel_size=filter_length, # n-gram range of each filter.
                    padding='same',  #valid: don't go off edge; same: use padding before applying filter
                    activation='relu',
                    name="CONV2",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.02))(embeddings)

conv3 = Conv1D(filters=32,  # Number of filters to use
                    kernel_size=filter_length, # n-gram range of each filter.
                    padding='same',  #valid: don't go off edge; same: use padding before applying filter
                    activation='relu',
                    name="CONV2",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.01))(embeddings)



max1 = MaxPool1D(10, strides=1,name="MaxPool1D1")(conv1)
max2 = MaxPool1D(10, strides=1,name="MaxPool1D2")(conv2)
max3 = MaxPool1D(10, strides=1,name="MaxPool1D2")(conv3)

conc = concatenate([max1, max2,max3])
flat = Flatten(name="FLATTEN")(max1)
....
```

Error is like following:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer CNN: expected shape=(None, 35), found shape=(None, 31)
```

The model :

```
Model: "CNN"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_19 (InputLayer)        [(None, 35)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
Embedding (Embedding)        (None, 35, 300)           4094700   
_________________________________________________________________
CONV1 (Conv1D)               (None, 35, 32)            48032     
_________________________________________________________________
MaxPool1D1 (MaxPooling1D)    (None, 26, 32)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
FLATTEN (Flatten)            (None, 832)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
Dropout (Dropout)            (None, 832)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
Dense (Dense)                (None, 3)                 2499      
=================================================================
Total params: 4,145,231
Trainable params: 4,145,231
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/100
```

Comment: That error comes when the dataset shape is not corresponding to the network input layer, so the problem isn't the network itself.

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: I think that you should post an example of the dataset and explain its shape, it would be helpful to give an answer.

Comment: I updated the question. I would be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Thank you it was problem of the shape of data set, my real shape was (7198, 31).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error comes when you have not matched the network's input layer shape and the dataset's shape. If are you receiving an error like this, then you should try:

1. Set the network input shape at `(None, 31)` so that it matches the Dataset's shape.
2. Check that the dataset's shape is equal to `(num_of_examples, 35)`.(Preferable)

If all of this informations are correct and there is no problem with the Dataset, it might be an error of the net itself, where the shapes af two adjcent layers don't match.